# Vertical line in longtable

Tags: spacing, longtable, rules

I would like my vertical line to be slightly detached from the horizontal lines. I am using

```
\usepackage{longtable}.

\footnotesize

\begin{longtable}{r | p{10cm}}

\caption{My caption 1\label{1}}\\

\hline

\endfirsthead

\caption[]{(continued)}\\

\endhead

\hline

\endlastfoot

\textsc{Newspaper Name}&\emph{Daily Triplicate}\\

\textsc{Availability}&text\\

\textsc{founded}&date\\

\textsc{Circulation}&number\\

\textsc{Coverage}&text\\

\textsc{Frequency}&text\\

\hline

\textsc{Newspaper Name}&\emph{Eureka Times-Standard}\\

\textsc{Availability}&text\\

\textsc{founded}&1997date\\

\textsc{Circulation}&number\\

\textsc{Coverage}&text\\

\textsc{Frequency}&text\\

\end{longtable}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use `booktabs` and its `toprule`, `midrule` and `bottomrule`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable,array}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{K}{>{\scshape}r}

\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{@{}K | p{10cm}@{}}
\caption{My caption 1\label{1}}\\
\toprule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{(continued)}\\
\endhead

\bottomrule

\endlastfoot

Newspaper Name  &   \emph{Daily Triplicate}\\
Availability    &   text    \\
founded         &   date    \\
Circulation     &   number  \\
Coverage        &   text    \\
Frequency       &   text    \\

\midrule

Newspaper Name  &   \emph{Eureka Times-Standard}\\
Availability    &   text        \\
founded         &   1997date    \\
Circulation     &   number      \\
Coverage        &   text        \\
Frequency       &   text        \\

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

As a free bonus, you get much nicer (and more correct) spacing of the rows.

*EDIT*: I have cleaned up the code by loading `array` and define a new `K`-column to get rid of all `\textsc{}` in the first column. Also `@{}` remove unnecessary space to the left in column 1 and to the right in column 2.

Also, I invite you to read *section 2* of the [booktab manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf), and reconsider the use of vertical lines.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. After all, I did reconsider the use of vertical lines and I don't need this anymore. Also, I am now using the top, mid and bottom lines as you suggested.